# how to bridge 2 set of edges of preserve the texture mapping (uv)?

Tags: edges

I tried to bridge to edges but the result has the textured altered or stretched. Maybe the closest thing is to adjust position of the vertex by sliding the edge (correct uv turn on) then do the bridge. But is there anyway i can have good result without have to edit the edge /vertex first to match the target ?

[image]

[image]

[image]